# Converting a translated filled curve into a region

Tags: graphics, regions

How do I convert a translated filled curve into a region?

It works without translation:

```
a = FilledCurve[{{{1, 3, 2}}}, {{{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}}}] // Graphics
a // DiscretizeGraphics // Region
```

It does not work with translation for no reason (since `b` is output of `Graphics` the same way as is `a`):

```
b = 
 Translate[
   FilledCurve[{{{1, 3, 2}}}, {{{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}}}], {0, 1}] // Graphics
b // DiscretizeGraphics // Region
```

Comment: My guess is that transformations such as `Translate`, `Rotate`, etc., are computed in the GPU when the graphics are display, and there is no way (AFAIK) to convert them to `Normal` graphics.  To me, it seems a gap in Mathematica's functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate the control point coordinates and proceed as before.

```
b = 
  With[{pts = TranslationTransform[{0, 1}][{{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}}]},
    FilledCurve[{{{1, 3, 2}}}, {pts}]] // Graphics;
b // DiscretizeGraphics // Region[#, Frame -> True] &
```

[image: region]

Comment: @azerbajdzan. Thanks for accepting my answer. But I don't understand why you considered it worth an acceptance but not worth an up-vote. You are aware, aren't you, that you can do both.

Answer (score 2):

You could discretize first and then translate:

```
a = FilledCurve[{{{1, 3, 2}}}, {{{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}}}] // 
  Graphics;

TransformedRegion[a // DiscretizeGraphics, 
 TranslationTransform[{0, 1}]]
```

Comment: I know this works, but I have have arguments that are translated first.